# How printf("%d","<string>") work in C?

Tags: c, string, int, printf

I was revising some C concepts and tried this:

```
printf("%d %d %d", "%da", 'a', 'A'); //16079992 97 65
```

I can understand that for `a` and `A`, it prints ASCII values : `97` and `65`. However I cant understand why it prints `16079992` for `"%da"`. In fact I dont understand how C interpretes strings when outputing them as integer with `%d`. There has to be some algorithm / logic behind that. Anyone?

Comment: "*There has to be some algorithm / logic behind that.*" No, there doesn't. If you cross the street without looking both ways, what will happen? Who knows. You might get hit by a car. You might get hit by a truck. Anything can happen. If you process information in a way that's specifically prohibited, you can get complete garbage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

String literals in C are arrays of char which in this context will decay to a pointer to the first element.

What you have is undefined behavior though, since you are misspecifying the format string in `printf` and telling it that the pointer is an *int* which it is not. Most compiler given the correct warning flags(*which we should always be using*) will provide a warning for this, for example `gcc` provides the following warning when using `-Wall`:

```
warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'char *' [-Wformat=]
printf("%d %d %d", "%da", 'a', 'A'); 
^
```

`clang` provides a similar warning it seems by default.

For reference, the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) tells us a string literal is a array of char in section `6.4.5` *String literals*:

> [...]initialize an array of static storage duration[...]For character
>   string literals, the array elements have type char, and are
>   initialized with the individual bytes of the multibyte character
>   sequence;[...]

decay to pointer is covered in section `6.3.2.1` *Lvalues, arrays, and function designators*:

> [...]an expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
>   expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
>   element of the array[...]

and we get undefined behavior from section `7.19.6.1` *The fprintf function*:

> [...]If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding
>   conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: !!! what are you? walking index of language specifications? Was just curious, if you have read formal specs of all these C variants?

Comment: @Mahesha999 no, I know enough to answer questions that can not be properly answered without a decent knowledge of the standards. There are plenty of SO users that know the standards very well, check out the [laguage-lawyer tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer), many who know it far better than I.

Comment: ok but still did u tried reading Formal Language Grammar of these C variants? May be that will encourage me.

Comment: @Mahesha999 well, the grammar is part of the standard. So the sections that deal with expressions, statements and declarations for example all include formal grammar.

Answer (score 0):

A string in C is a pointer, which has a numeric value (the address). So printf is just printing the address of the string there.

Comment: Actually, it is undefined behaviour. On a 64 bit compiler %d will definitely not print the address of the string, and on other compilers it might not.